# Angular - can't install Moment and Material Moment Adapter

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material, momentjs

I need both Material and Material-Moment-Adapter to change date format in datepicker controls.
I install moment using:

```
npm install moment --save
```

and Material-Moment-Adapter:

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

after installation I see following error:

Error: The target entry-point "@angular/material-moment-adapter" has missing dependencies:

- moment

but I have installed Moment before, so I try installing Moment again but it removes Material-Moment-Adapter from my Angular project.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Installing two things in one npm install comand

```
npm i moment @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

Comment: You should be able to mark this as the answer, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command using npm for installing `@angular/material-moment-adapter`:

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

Comment: The command you are suggesting is 1:1 the command from OP's question, where OP claims it's not working.